# Create a view with dynamic column headers based on original table row data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Given the two sample tables here:

**Tickets Table**

```
ID  User    Description
------------------------------------    
0   James   This is a support ticket
1   Fred    This is a ticket too
```

**Properties Table**

```
ID  TicketID    Label           Value
---------------------------------------------------------
0   0           Engineer        Scott
1   1           Engineer        Dale
2   0           Manu            Dell
3   1           Manu            HP
4   0           OS              Windows
5   1           OS              Linux
```

How can I arrive at a view like this:

```
ID  User    Description                 Engineer    Manu    OS
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1   James   This is a support ticket    Scott       Dell    Windows
2   Fred    This is a ticket too        Dale        HP      Linux
```

It is important to note that the properties table would not always be the same. Some tickets may have properties that others do not.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You need [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10986031/877069 Please don't cross-post.

Comment: Yeah, I actually posted there inadvertantly, then realized it should be here.  By the time I got back there to delete it it had a correct answer!  Sorry!

Comment: No problem.  Since you got an answer there already, please delete this post.

Comment: I kinda wanted it here in case someone else finds it useful, especially since it already has 2 upvotes.  But I don't want to give myself credit for answering (I posted the answer, but I won't accept it).  Can we "close" this question instead of deleting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by Bluefeet in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986031/sql-dynamic-view-with-column-names-based-on-column-values-in-source-table

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.label) 
                    from tickets t
                    inner join properties p
                        on t.id = p.ticketid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, [user], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select t.id
                        , t.[user]
                        , p.ticketid
                        , p.label
                        , p.value
                    from tickets t
                    inner join properties p
                        on t.id = p.ticketid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(value)
                for label in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```